# Необходимо пояснение кода ViewModel и Coroutine

Tags: android, mvvm, coroutine

Нашел одну статью по MVVM c Coroutine.

```
    class MovieViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
        private val repository: MovieRepository
        val allMovies: LiveData<List<MovieEntity>>

        init {
            val movieDao = MovieDatabase.getInstance(application).movieDao()
            repository = MovieRepository(movieDao)
            allMovies = repository.allMovies
        }

        fun insert(movie: MovieEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insert(movie)
        }
    }

class MovieRepository(private val movieDao: MovieDao) {
    val allMovies: LiveData<List<MovieEntity>> = movieDao.getAll()

    suspend fun insert(movie: MovieEntity) {
        movieDao.insert(movie)
    }
}

@Query("SELECT * FROM movie_items ORDER BY title ASC")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<MovieEntity>>
```

Может кто объяснить, почему для того чтобы получить allMovies из базы данных, автор не использует coroutine, а для Insert использует?

Вот еще код, только уже с git - репозитория другого автора

```
class AllTaskViewModel constructor(private val taskDao: TaskDao) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _mTasks = NonNullMediatorLiveData<List<Task>>()
    val tasks: LiveData<List<Task>> = _mTasks

    fun allTasks() = launch(coroutineContext) {
        _mTasks.postValue(taskDao.tasks())
    }

    fun deleteTask(task: Task) = launch(coroutineContext){
        taskDao.deleteTask(task)
        allTasks()
    }
}



  @Dao
interface TaskDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertTask(t: Task): Long

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tasks")
    suspend fun tasks(): List<Task>

    @Update
    suspend fun updateTask(t: Task)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteTask(t: Task)
}
```

Здесь же и для получения использует Coroutine.

Также не понятно дела с LiveData.
Первый автор использует на всех уровнях (ViewModel -> Repository -> Dao) LiveData
А второй только на уровне ViewModel.

Как нужно делать правильно?

**Моя задача:**

Мне необходимо наблюдать за изменениями данных в БД, одновременно мапить ClassEntity в class бизнес логики. Так как это может выполняться долго, нужно использовать coroutine (о чем Room говорит).

Но как это использовать с наблюдением я пока мало понимаю.
Одновременно мне нужно еще с экземплярами бизнес класса менять параметры. Но так как результат у меня приходит в LiveData, я не могу его конвертировать в MutableLiveData, чтобы работать с ним.

Мой код:

**Dao** . Здесь если я буду использовать LiveData, то я не смогу потом эти данные конвертировать в другой бизнес - класc, поэтому пока использую обычный List.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM record")
    suspend fun getAllRecording() : List<RecordEntity>
```

**Repository**. Здесь я mapy один класс в другой. Но так как эта долгая операция, Room Требует чтобы я не использовал Main thread. Поэтому я в Dao обернул в suspend. Но теперь я не знаю, как на этом уровне мапить.

```
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase){
    private var allRecords = appDatabase.getRecordDao().getAllRecording().map { it.toItem() } -----не будет работать из-за suspend

    fun getAllRecording(): List<RecordItem> {
        return allRecords
    }
```

}

**ViewModel**. Здесь я не могу возвращать LiveData, так как потом не смогу выполнить метод handleSelect, поэтому надо возвращать обычный List и наблюдать за ним MutableLiveData.
Но для этого требуется coroutine. И я пока не могу понять, как реализовать вместе и Coroutine и наблюдение, и еще чтобы была возможность изменить данные в handleSelect().

```
class RecordListViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: RecordRepository): ViewModel() {
    private var records =  mutableLiveData(repository.getAllRecording())

    fun getAllRecords() = records

    fun handleSelectedItem(id : Int){
        records.value = records.value?.map {
            if(it.id == id) it.copy(isSelected = true)
            else it.copy(isSelected = false)

        }
    }
}

fun <T> mutableLiveData(defaultValue: T? = null): MutableLiveData<T>{
    val data = MutableLiveData<T>()

    if(defaultValue != null) {
        data.value = defaultValue
    }
    return data

}
```

Также я уже смотрел [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454829/room-with-kotlin-coroutines-observe-db-changes), но у меня нету такого функционала, хотя версии стоят самые последние

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
ext.coroutines_version = '1.3.0'
ext.room_version = "2.2.2"
```

Надеюсь, кто-нибудь мне поможет с этим разобраться.

Comment: `suspend` не используется для `getAll` потому что возвращается `LiveData`, поток управления не требуется останавливать до получения данных, `LiveData` возвращается сразу, в которую попадёт выборка, когда будет готова. При этом, если данная таблица изменится, то в `LiveData` поступит новое значение. Т.е. это для постоянного наблюдения данных из базы данных. `suspend` же функции в `Dao` приостанавливаются до получения данных, и ,естественно, это просто данные из БД на текущий момент, т.е. если вам понадобятся свежие данные, то нужно будет повторить запрос.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon т.е первый автор прав?
А если на уровне Repository автору нужно сначала получить данные с удаленного сервиса, внести в базу данных и потом получить данные и наблюдать за ними, что тогда бы изменилось? Желательно кодом показать, чтобы я понял

Comment: Тут нет прав/неправ, зависит от задачи. Если у вас данные в БД изменяются и вам нужно эти изменения обрабатывать, то используйте LiveData. И если вам нужно сначала подгрузить данные по сети, то убедитесь, что на LiveData вы подпишетесь после получения данных и занесения их в БД, иначе вам в LiveData придут либо старые данные, либо пустой лист, а потом уже новые данные

Comment: @danilshik, вы все бьетесь с этой темой :) Может вот это видео вам поможет? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8ppnjGPAGE

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja посмотрел я это видео, хоть с английским у меня не очень. Но эти возможности у меня нету, хотя я обновился до последних версий, значит это еще в альфе версиях. Даже у них в их приложении этого функционала еще нет https://github.com/android/sunflower.

Comment: Это все доступно в 2.2, как я понимаю. RC2 вышел в ноябре https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я добавил свой код и указал проблемы, пока не могу разобраться, буду благодарен, если вы поможете

Comment: `"Здесь если я буду использовать LiveData, то я не смогу потом эти данные конвертировать в другой бизнес - класc, поэтому пока использую обычный List.
"` Почему не сможете? [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) в помощь. Есть экстеншен для LiveData. Вам даже не придётся переделывать строчку `appDatabase.getRecordDao().getAllRecording().map { it.toItem() }`, при этом будет records будет `LiveData<List<RecordItem>>`

Comment: @DrawnRaccon, если records будет LiveData, как я выполню метод handleSelectedItem, ведь у LiveData нету .value, оно есть только у MutableLiveData

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут пример для вашего репозитория:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata

Код получается такой.

```
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase){
    fun getAllRecording(): LiveData<List<RecordItem>> = liveData {
        val allRecords = appDatabase.getRecordDao().getAllRecording().map { it.toItem() }
        emit(allRecords)
    }
}
```

Какие зависимости добавлять, описано тут
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies

Comment: Хорошо, в ViewModel теперь private var records : LiveData<List<RecordItem>> = repository.getAllRecording()).
Как мне теперь получить к значению этого LiveData? Мне нужно выполнить метод handleSelectedItem(), но у liveData я не могу получить .value, оно имеется только у MutableLiveData?

Comment: `LiveData is an observable data holder class.` Подписываетесь и получаете. Вы уже взялись за корутины, не разобравшись как без них работает.  
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata